# how to grep multiples variable in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I need to grep multiple strings, but i don't know the exact number of strings. 
My code is :

```
s2=( $(echo $1 | awk -F"," '{ for (i=1; i<=NF ; i++) {print $i} }') )    
for pattern in "${s2[@]}"; do
    ssh -q host tail -f /some/path | 
      grep -w -i --line-buffered "$pattern" > some_file 2>/dev/null &
done
```

now, the code is not doing what it's supposed to do. For example if i run ./script s1,s2,s3,s4,.....

it prints all lines that contain s1,s2,s3....

The script is supposed to do something like grep "$s1" | grep "$s2" | grep "$s3" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` doesn't have an option to match *all* of a set of patterns. So the best solution is to use another tool, such as `awk` (or your choice of scripting languages, but awk will work fine).

Note, however, that `awk` and `grep` have subtly different regular expression implementations. It's not clear from the question whether the target strings are literal strings or regular expression patterns, and if the latter, what the expectations are. However, since the argument comes delimited with commas, I'm assuming that the pieces are simple strings and should *not* be interpreted as patterns.

If you want the strings to be interpreted as patterns, you can change `index` to `match` in the following little program:

```
ssh -q host tail -f /some/path |
awk -v STRINGS="$1" -v IGNORECASE=1 \
    'BEGIN{split(STRINGS,strings,/,/)}
     {for(i in strings)if(!index($0,strings[i]))next}
     {print;fflush()}'
```

Note:

1. `IGNORECASE` is only available in gnu awk; in (most) other implementations, it will do nothing. It seems that is what you want, based on the fact that you used `-i` in your grep invocation.
2. `fflush()` is also an extension, although it works with both `gawk` and `mawk`. In Posix `awk`, `fflush` requires an argument; if you were using Posix `awk`, you'd be better off printing to `stderr`.

Comment: i didnt use fflush. Im not sure i understand what it does, but im directing the ouput of tail to a file, and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @user2864207: `fflush()` does the same thing as the grep option `--line-buffered`; that is, it forces every output line to be written immediately instead of being buffered.

Comment: i have a slight problem. the process does not run in the background. I need to kill tail before i can view the lines in the file

Comment: @user2864207 That's probably why you need the `fflush()`.

Comment: @user2864207: Sorry, I don't understand what that has to do with anything. Neither awk nor tail produce any output to stderr; the only thing that might be written to stderr are connection errors from `ssh`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, your answer works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use extended [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)

```
egrep "$s1|$s2|$s3" fileName
```

If you don't know how many pattern you need to grep, but you have all of them in an array called `s`, you can use

```
egrep $(sed 's/ /|/g' <<< "${s[@]}") fileName
```

This creates a `herestring` with all elements of the array, [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) replaces the field separator of bash (space) with `|` and if we feed that to [egrep](/questions/tagged/egrep) we [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) all strings that are in the array `s`.

Comment: i can't, because i don't know how many strings i am supposed to grep

Comment: i have entered the following line ssh -q host tail -f some/path | egrep -w -i --line-buffered "$(sed 's/ /|/g' <<< "${s2[@]}")" > file
It gives me a snytax error

Comment: It's difficult to debug since I don't know what `ssh -q host tail -f some/path` outputs, but when I replace that with an `echo` command, it works for me. What's the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
a=" $@"
grep ${a// / -e } .bashrc
```

it works that way:

```
$ ./test.sh 1 2 3
+ a=' 1 2 3'
+ grep -e 1 -e 2 -e 3 .bashrc
(here is lots of text that fits all the arguments)
```